# ant eclipse build.xml does not exist

Tags: eclipse, ant

I tried ant eclipse
and I got the msg below.

> Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed

Searching the net, some says build.xml is from ant and need to install but when I check ant -version, I am already on ant 1.9.7.

What do I need to do to make ant eclipse work? I have already installed eclipse 3.8.

Comment: The purpose of the Ant tool is to execute a build.xml that **you** must write. Eclipse 3.8 is ancient, Eclipse 4.7.1a is the current release.

Comment: I was just following the instructions here https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/floodlightcontroller/pages/1343544/Installation+Guide, it didn't mention that I need to write one...how should I write one?  

This is the version of eclipse that I downloaded. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz
It didn't really show the version until after I installed it.

Comment: The `ant eclipse` in that blog is running the `ant` program with a target of `eclipse`. This is using a build.xml which appears to be part of the floodlight code.

Comment: It looks like you skipped the part where you need to checkout this repo https://github.com/floodlight/floodlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know it is late but i have had this problem before and solve it like this:

When you write "ant" to command prompt it may not work so **if you know where is your build.xml file**, you should write the path in command prompt and open it. Then it works, **if you dont have build.xml** file, you should create it with your project then open it by writing specific path in command prompt.

For example: build.xml is here in my computer, D:\Code\den\java\condentry\build.xml

I hope this helps, it worked for me.